# Use spyder library to save all variables into spydata file

Tags: python-3.x, spyder

I have met with a problem when I switch from python 2.7 to python 3.3. I used spyderlib but now it upgrades to spyder. Therefore, I have revised my code to save all the variables into a spydata data as below:

```
from spyder.utils.iofuncs import save_dictionary
def variablesfilter():
    from spyder.widgets.variableexplorer.utils import globalsfilter
    from spyder.plugins.variableexplorer import VariableExplorer
    from spyder.config.base import get_conf_path, get_supported_types

    data = globals()
    settings = VariableExplorer.get_settings()

    get_supported_types()
    data = globalsfilter(data,                   
                         check_all=True,
                         filters=tuple(get_supported_types()['picklable']),
                         exclude_private=settings['exclude_private'],
                         exclude_uppercase=settings['exclude_uppercase'],
                         exclude_capitalized=settings['exclude_capitalized'],
                         exclude_unsupported=settings['exclude_unsupported'],
                         excluded_names=settings['excluded_names']+['settings','In'])
    return data

def saveglobals(filename):
    data = variablesfilter()
    save_dictionary(data,filename)


savepath = 'memory.spydata'
saveglobals(savepath)
```

However, it throws our an error like below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\jialiang.shen\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3_new\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 880, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\jialiang.shen\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3_new\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
  File "C:/Users/jialiang.shen/temp/s1.py", line 37, in <module>
    saveglobals(savepath) 
  File "C:/Users/jialiang.shen/temp/s1.py", line 32, in saveglobals
    data = variablesfilter()
  File "C:/Users/jialiang.shen/temp/s1.py", line 18, in variablesfilter
    settings = VariableExplorer.get_settings()
TypeError: get_settings() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

This error should be originated from the upgrade of library spyderlib to spyder. Can anyone help me with it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to instantiate VariableExplorer class:

```
settings = VariableExplorer(None).get_settings()
```

Comment: I have tried this method but python get crashed after I made this change. Any thoughts?